# How to Convert mupdfActivity into fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, mupdf

I have successfully implemented the mupdf library in my project.

The issue is the activity

```
 MuPDFActivity
```

only showing a single window containing pdf.  What I need is to convert this activity into fragment so that I can show it more than once simultaneously.

Comment: possible duplicate of this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803076/mupdf-for-android-option-for-fragment-instead-activity