# MuPDF for Android: Option for fragment instead Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-viewpager, android-view, mupdf

In my existing android app, Im using MuPDF, which i ported with help of [this doc.](http://www.mupdf.com/doc/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android)
Now when i want to open pdf files inside activity i use :
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MuPDFActivity.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
```

which fires a new activity, My problem is: (1) how can I start Fragment to view pdf?
(2) Does MuPDF supports Fragment that I can call under my currant Android-Tab-View?
(3) Is there a Way Converting this activity into fragment?

Currently i'm doing:

```
public class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View  rootView = null;

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dummy_section_fragment, container, false);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MuPDFActivity.class);
            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myIntent.setData(uri);
            getActivity().startActivity(myIntent); 

            return rootView;
        }
}
```

Which: opens a new activity on my current Tab View layout, which does not look great as it covers entire tab layout and user have to click `BACK` button to view tab view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you shouldn't use the MuPDFActivity in your project - it's just an example how Mupdf works. All what you need is the MuPDFReaderView/MuPDFCore/MuPDFPageAdapter. MuPDFReaderView extends from View/ViewGroup, so you can just add it to your layout. Try it like this (totally untested!!):

1.) XML --> The base layout for the fragment (mupdf_wrapper.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mupdf_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</RelativeLayout>
```

2.) JAVA:

```
public class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View  rootView = null;

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mupdf_wrapper, container, false);
        RelativeLayout mupdfWrapper (RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mupdf_wrapper);
        String path = "path/To/Your/PDF/File.pdf";
        MuPDFCore core = new MuPDFCore(getActivity(), path);
        MuPDFReaderView mDocView = new MuPDFReaderView(getActivity());
        mDocView.setAdapter(new MuPDFPageAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity(), core));
        mupdfWrapper .addView(mDocView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return rootView;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Converting activity to fragment :

```
public class a extend activity{

     public void oncreate(Bundle Saveinstance)
     {
     super.oncreate(saveinstance);
     setcontentview(r.layout.xyz);
     }    
    }
```

Converting ... :

```
  public class a extend fragment{


 public void onstart()
 {
 super.onstart();

 }   

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    return inflater.inflate(com.example.login.R.layout.fragment, container, false);

} 
}
```

If you have a function or you wanna make a Toast , and you have xyz.this replace him with `getActivity()`

```
Toast.makeText(xyz.this, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```