# Android: Display pdf in fragments using MuPDF

Tags: android

can I display PDF using MuPDF in fragments instead of doing it in activity.

gone through this question [MuPDF for Android: Option for fragment instead Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803076/mupdf-for-android-option-for-fragment-instead-activity)

but I couldn't solve my problem please anyone help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not the best of doing thing , but I was in a similar problem few days back , so here's what I did

**Edited Code**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.*;
import com.docutools.android.R;

public class PdfViewer extends Fragment {

    /* The core rendering instance */
    private enum LinkState {
        DEFAULT, HIGHLIGHT, INHIBIT
    }

    ;

    public static final String KEY_INTENT_ACTION = "key.intent.action";
    private final int TAP_PAGE_MARGIN = 5;
    private static final int SEARCH_PROGRESS_DELAY = 200;
    private MuPDFCore core;
    private String mFileName;
    private ReaderView mDocView;
    private View mButtonsView;
    private boolean mButtonsVisible;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private TextView mFilenameView;
    private SeekBar mPageSlider;
    private int mPageSliderRes;
    private TextView mPageNumberView;
    private ImageButton mSearchButton;
    private ImageButton mCancelButton;
    private ImageButton mOutlineButton;
    private ViewSwitcher mTopBarSwitcher;
    // XXX  private ImageButton  mLinkButton;
    private boolean mTopBarIsSearch;
    private ImageButton mSearchBack;
    private ImageButton mSearchFwd;
    private EditText mSearchText;
    private SafeAsyncTask<Void, Integer, SearchTaskResult> mSearchTask;
    //private SearchTaskResult mSearchTaskResult;
    private AlertDialog.Builder mAlertBuilder;
    private LinkState mLinkState = LinkState.DEFAULT;
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    // send this as Fragment Argument
    protected Intent intent;

    public static PdfViewer getInstance(Intent intent) {
        PdfViewer pdfViewer = new PdfViewer();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(KEY_INTENT_ACTION, intent);

        pdfViewer.setArguments(args);

        return pdfViewer;
    }

    private MuPDFCore openFile(String path) {
        int lastSlashPos = path.lastIndexOf('/');
        mFileName = new String(lastSlashPos == -1
                ? path
                : path.substring(lastSlashPos + 1));
        System.out.println("Trying to open " + path);
        try {
            core = new MuPDFCore(path);
            // New file: drop the old outline data
            OutlineActivityData.set(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
        return core;
    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        intent = getArguments().getParcelable(KEY_INTENT_ACTION);

        mAlertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        if (core == null) {
            if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Uri uri = intent.getData();
                if (uri.toString().startsWith("content://media/external/file")) {
                    // Handle view requests from the Transformer Prime's file manager
                    // Hopefully other file managers will use this same scheme, if not
                    // using explicit paths.
                    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{"_data"}, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(0));
                    }
                }
                core = openFile(Uri.decode(uri.getEncodedPath()));
                SearchTaskResult.set(null);
            }
            if (core != null && core.needsPassword()) {
                // requestPassword(savedInstanceState);
                return;
            }
        }
        if (core == null) {
            AlertDialog alert = mAlertBuilder.create();
            alert.setTitle(com.artifex.mupdf.R.string.open_failed);
            alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Dismiss",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            getFragmentHolder().popFragment();
                        }
                    }
            );
            alert.show();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return createUI();
    }

    public RelativeLayout createUI() {
        if (core == null)
            return null;
        // Now create the UI.
        // First create the document view making use of the ReaderView's internal
        // gesture recognition
        mDocView = new ReaderView(getActivity()) {
            private boolean showButtonsDisabled;

            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                if (e.getX() < super.getWidth() / TAP_PAGE_MARGIN) {
                    super.moveToPrevious();
                } else if (e.getX() > super.getWidth() * (TAP_PAGE_MARGIN - 1) / TAP_PAGE_MARGIN) {
                    super.moveToNext();
                } else if (!showButtonsDisabled) {
                    int linkPage = -1;
                    if (mLinkState != LinkState.INHIBIT) {
                        MuPDFPageView pageView = (MuPDFPageView) mDocView.getDisplayedView();
                        if (pageView != null) {
// XXX                          linkPage = pageView.hitLinkPage(e.getX(), e.getY());
                        }
                    }

                    if (linkPage != -1) {
                        mDocView.setDisplayedViewIndex(linkPage);
                    } else {
                        if (!mButtonsVisible) {
                            showButtons();
                        } else {
                            hideButtons();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
            }

            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                if (!showButtonsDisabled)
                    hideButtons();

                return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
            }

            public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector d) {
                // Disabled showing the buttons until next touch.
                // Not sure why this is needed, but without it
                // pinch zoom can make the buttons appear
                showButtonsDisabled = true;
                return super.onScaleBegin(d);
            }

            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    showButtonsDisabled = false;

                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

            protected void onChildSetup(int i, View v) {
                if (SearchTaskResult.get() != null && SearchTaskResult.get().pageNumber == i)
                    ((PageView) v).setSearchBoxes(SearchTaskResult.get().searchBoxes);
                else
                    ((PageView) v).setSearchBoxes(null);

                ((PageView) v).setLinkHighlighting(mLinkState == LinkState.HIGHLIGHT);
            }

            protected void onMoveToChild(int i) {
                if (core == null)
                    return;
                mPageNumberView.setText(String.format("%d/%d", i + 1, core.countPages()));
                mPageSlider.setMax((core.countPages() - 1) * mPageSliderRes);
                mPageSlider.setProgress(i * mPageSliderRes);
                if (SearchTaskResult.get() != null && SearchTaskResult.get().pageNumber != i) {
                    SearchTaskResult.set(null);
                    mDocView.resetupChildren();
                }
            }

            protected void onSettle(View v) {
                // When the layout has settled ask the page to render
                // in HQ
                ((PageView) v).addHq();
            }

            protected void onUnsettle(View v) {
                // When something changes making the previous settled view
                // no longer appropriate, tell the page to remove HQ
                ((PageView) v).removeHq();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onNotInUse(View v) {
                ((PageView) v).releaseResources();
            }
        };
        mDocView.setAdapter(new MuPDFPageAdapter(getActivity(), core));

        // Make the buttons overlay, and store all its
        // controls in variables
        makeButtonsView();

        // Set up the page slider
        int smax = Math.max(core.countPages() - 1, 1);
        mPageSliderRes = ((10 + smax - 1) / smax) * 2;

        // Set the file-name text
        mFilenameView.setText(mFileName);

        // Activate the seekbar
        mPageSlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                mDocView.setDisplayedViewIndex((seekBar.getProgress() + mPageSliderRes / 2) / mPageSliderRes);
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                updatePageNumView((progress + mPageSliderRes / 2) / mPageSliderRes);
            }
        });

        mSearchButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // Activate the search-preparing button
        mSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchModeOn();
            }
        });

        mCancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchModeOff();
            }
        });

        // Search invoking buttons are disabled while there is no text specified
        mSearchBack.setEnabled(false);
        mSearchFwd.setEnabled(false);

        // React to interaction with the text widget
        mSearchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                boolean haveText = s.toString().length() > 0;
                mSearchBack.setEnabled(haveText);
                mSearchFwd.setEnabled(haveText);

                // Remove any previous search results
                if (SearchTaskResult.get() != null && !mSearchText.getText().toString().equals(SearchTaskResult.get().txt)) {
                    SearchTaskResult.set(null);
                    mDocView.resetupChildren();
                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
            }
        });

        //React to Done button on keyboard
        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
                    search(1);
                return false;
            }
        });

        mSearchText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                    search(1);
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Activate search invoking buttons
        mSearchBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                search(-1);
            }
        });
        mSearchFwd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                search(1);
            }
        });

/* XXX
        mLinkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(mLinkState) {
                case DEFAULT:
                    mLinkState = LinkState.HIGHLIGHT;
                    mLinkButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_hl_link);
                    //Inform pages of the change.
                    mDocView.resetupChildren();
                    break;
                case HIGHLIGHT:
                    mLinkState = LinkState.INHIBIT;
                    mLinkButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_nolink);
                    //Inform pages of the change.
                    mDocView.resetupChildren();
                    break;
                case INHIBIT:
                    mLinkState = LinkState.DEFAULT;
                    mLinkButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_link);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
*/

        if (core.hasOutline()) {
            mOutlineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    OutlineItem outline[] = core.getOutline();
                    if (outline != null) {
                        OutlineActivityData.get().items = outline;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OutlineActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            mOutlineButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Reenstate last state if it was recorded
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mDocView.setDisplayedViewIndex(prefs.getInt("page" + mFileName, 0));

       /* if (savedInstanceState == null || !savedInstanceState.getBoolean("ButtonsHidden", false))
            showButtons();

        if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean("SearchMode", false))
            searchModeOn();*/

        // Stick the document view and the buttons overlay into a parent view
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        layout.addView(mDocView);
        layout.addView(mButtonsView);
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tiled_background);
        //layout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.canvas);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode >= 0)
            mDocView.setDisplayedViewIndex(resultCode);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        killSearch();

        if (mFileName != null && mDocView != null) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putInt("page" + mFileName, mDocView.getDisplayedViewIndex());
            edit.commit();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (core != null)
            core.onDestroy();
        core = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    void showButtons() {
        if (core == null)
            return;
        if (!mButtonsVisible) {
            mButtonsVisible = true;
            // Update page number text and slider
            int index = mDocView.getDisplayedViewIndex();
            updatePageNumView(index);
            mPageSlider.setMax((core.countPages() - 1) * mPageSliderRes);
            mPageSlider.setProgress(index * mPageSliderRes);
            if (mTopBarIsSearch) {
                mSearchText.requestFocus();
                showKeyboard();
            }

            Animation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -mTopBarSwitcher.getHeight(), 0);
            anim.setDuration(200);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    mTopBarSwitcher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                }
            });
            mTopBarSwitcher.startAnimation(anim);

            anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, mPageSlider.getHeight(), 0);
            anim.setDuration(200);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    mPageSlider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    mPageNumberView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            mPageSlider.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }

    void hideButtons() {
        if (mButtonsVisible) {
            mButtonsVisible = false;
            hideKeyboard();

            Animation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -mTopBarSwitcher.getHeight());
            anim.setDuration(200);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    mTopBarSwitcher.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
            mTopBarSwitcher.startAnimation(anim);

            anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, mPageSlider.getHeight());
            anim.setDuration(200);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    mPageNumberView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    mPageSlider.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
            mPageSlider.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }

    void searchModeOn() {
        if (!mTopBarIsSearch) {
            mTopBarIsSearch = true;
            //Focus on EditTextWidget
            mSearchText.requestFocus();
            showKeyboard();
            mTopBarSwitcher.showNext();
        }
    }

    void searchModeOff() {
        if (mTopBarIsSearch) {
            mTopBarIsSearch = false;
            hideKeyboard();
            mTopBarSwitcher.showPrevious();
            SearchTaskResult.set(null);
            // Make the ReaderView act on the change to mSearchTaskResult
            // via overridden onChildSetup method.
            mDocView.resetupChildren();
        }
    }

    void updatePageNumView(int index) {
        if (core == null)
            return;
        mPageNumberView.setText(String.format("%d/%d", index + 1, core.countPages()));
    }

    void makeButtonsView() {
        mButtonsView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.buttons, null);
        mFilenameView = (TextView) mButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.docNameText);
        mPageSlider = (SeekBar) mButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.pageSlider);
        mPageNumberView = (TextView) mButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.pageNumber);
        mSearchButton = (ImageButton) mButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        mCancelButton = (ImageButton) mButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        mOutlineButton = (ImageButton) mButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.outlineButton);
        mTopBarSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) mButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.switcher);
        mSearchBack = (ImageButton) mButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.searchBack);
        mSearchFwd = (ImageButton) mButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.searchForward);
        mSearchText = (EditText) mButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.searchText);
// XXX      mLinkButton = (ImageButton)mButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.linkButton);
        mTopBarSwitcher.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mPageNumberView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mPageSlider.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    void showKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null)
            imm.showSoftInput(mSearchText, 0);
    }

    void hideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null)
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mSearchText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    void killSearch() {
        if (mSearchTask != null) {
            mSearchTask.cancel(true);
            mSearchTask = null;
        }
    }

    void search(int direction) {
        hideKeyboard();
        if (core == null)
            return;
        killSearch();

        final int increment = direction;
        final int startIndex = SearchTaskResult.get() == null ? mDocView.getDisplayedViewIndex() : SearchTaskResult.get().pageNumber + increment;

        final ProgressDialogX progressDialog = new ProgressDialogX(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.searching_));
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                killSearch();
            }
        });
        progressDialog.setMax(core.countPages());

        mSearchTask = new SafeAsyncTask<Void, Integer, SearchTaskResult>() {
            @Override
            protected SearchTaskResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
                int index = startIndex;

                while (0 <= index && index < core.countPages() && !isCancelled()) {
                    publishProgress(index);
                    RectF searchHits[] = core.searchPage(index, mSearchText.getText().toString());

                    if (searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0)
                        return new SearchTaskResult(mSearchText.getText().toString(), index, searchHits);

                    index += increment;
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(SearchTaskResult result) {
                progressDialog.cancel();
                if (result != null) {
                    // Ask the ReaderView to move to the resulting page
                    mDocView.setDisplayedViewIndex(result.pageNumber);
                    SearchTaskResult.set(result);
                    // Make the ReaderView act on the change to mSearchTaskResult
                    // via overridden onChildSetup method.
                    mDocView.resetupChildren();
                } else {
                    mAlertBuilder.setTitle(SearchTaskResult.get() == null ? R.string.text_not_found : R.string.no_further_occurences_found);
                    AlertDialog alert = mAlertBuilder.create();
                    alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Dismiss",
                            (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null);
                    alert.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onCancelled() {
                super.onCancelled();
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                progressDialog.setProgress(values[0].intValue());
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (!progressDialog.isCancelled()) {
                            progressDialog.show();
                            progressDialog.setProgress(startIndex);
                        }
                    }
                }, SEARCH_PROGRESS_DELAY);
            }
        };

        mSearchTask.safeExecute();
    }
}

class ProgressDialogX extends ProgressDialog {
    public ProgressDialogX(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private boolean mCancelled = false;

    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return mCancelled;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        mCancelled = true;
        super.cancel();
    }
}

class SearchTaskResult {
    public final String txt;
    public final int   pageNumber;
    public final RectF searchBoxes[];
    static private SearchTaskResult singleton;

    SearchTaskResult(String _txt, int _pageNumber, RectF _searchBoxes[]) {
        txt = _txt;
        pageNumber = _pageNumber;
        searchBoxes = _searchBoxes;
    }

    static public SearchTaskResult get() {
        return singleton;
    }

    static public void set(SearchTaskResult r) {
        singleton = r;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

use `PdfViewer.getInstance(intent);` to get the instance of `PdfViewer`

Comment: can you tell me how to put files for corresponding list item click.. in my app it displays only for first item..

Comment: shubhang.. please tell me how to pass intent as a fragment argument please share the code if you did it. thanks..

Comment: @namitha I have updated my code , please take a look

Comment: Incorrect number of arguments for type SafeAsyncTask<ResultT>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Void, Integer, SearchTaskResultFra> I am getting this error. Also .addHq gives error.